# I want to add a button to Submenu

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to add a button to Submenu.

```
var menuRegister = new List<SubItem>();
menuRegister.Add(new SubItem("Customer"));
menuRegister.Add(new SubItem("Providers"));
menuRegister.Add(new SubItem("Employees"));
menuRegister.Add(new SubItem("Products"));
var item6 = new ItemMenu("Register", menuRegister, PackIconKind.Register);
Menu.Children.Add(new UserControlMenuItem(item0));`
```

I am trying to understand how to create objects on C#.
Usually I create buttons on XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

XAML:

```
<Window...

<DockPanel>
     <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top"
       <MenuItem Header="_Register">
          <MenuItem Header="_Customer" />
          <MenuItem Header="_Providers" />
          <MenuItem Header="_Employees" />
          <MenuItem Header="_Products" />
       </MenuItem>
     </Menu>

     <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">


     </Grid>
</DockPanel>

</Window>
```